# Event Handler in javaFx for menu

Tags: javafx, menu, event-handling

I have a question in JavaFX , how can i set an event Handler for menu (not menu bar or menu item)  that when i clicked on the menu a popup window appear. i have tried this but when i click on menu nothing happens:

```
settingsMenu.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,event -> {//To DO});
```

and even the code below doesn't works:

```
settingMenu.setOnAction(event -> {//To Do});
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't; the menu won't fire an action event (and certainly doesn't fire mouse events; it's not a `Node`). Does `settingsMenu.showingProperty().addListener(...)` do what you want?

Comment: Thanks,i'll try it.

Comment: Typically you don't care about a user clicking on a menu; the menu just shows its menu items when you do so. Why do you want a listener for this?

Comment: because i have a menu called settings but it's components can not be show as menu items , so i want to show the in a single stage

Comment: What do you mean by "its components can not be shown as menu items"? If it doesn't contain menu items, it's not a menu. This just sounds like you have tried to use the wrong approach for whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: if you mean this         settingsMenu.showingProperty().addListener(observable -> {
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }); it doesn't work for me.

Comment: i know what you say but my menu bar is not a simple one it is a combination of title bar and menu bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack. `Menu` has a constructor `Menu(String text, Node graphic)`. Set the `String` to `empty-string` and the `Node` to `Label`. Then add a `MouseListener` to the `Label`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaFXApplication33 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Help!");
        label.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent->{System.out.println("Hello World!");});
        Menu menu = new Menu("", label);
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);


        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(menuBar);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```